# Apache Load Balancing

Tags: apache, load-balancing

Hello im new on Apache Server i try to do a load balance over my local machine with multiple page on different folder load1,load2 i try to do a configuration according to the documentation but i cant see the effect here is my config

```
<VirtualHost *:1000>

ProxyRequests Off
      ProxyTimeout 300
      ProxyPreserveHost On
      ProxyVia On

ErrorLog "logs/yoni-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/yoni-access.log" common
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>

   BalancerMember http://yoni.com:1000 
   BalancerMember http://yoni1.com:1000 

   ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests

</Proxy>
ProxyPass /load balancer://mycluster/
ProxyPassReverse /load balancer://mycluster/
<Location /balancer-manager>
    SetHandler balancer-manager
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What do you want to see as effect?

Comment: thanks for your fast response. when ever i refresh the page i want to see different page from different directory